# Wasm compilation exceeds internal limits in this context for the provided arguments

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

So I am trying to create a WebAssembly Module from an ArrayBuffer.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
      printf("hello, world!\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I compile it like so:

```
$ emcc -O2 hello.c -s WASM=1 -o hello.html
```

I start a local http server.
And I try to load it in my browser like so:

```
fetch('hello.wasm')
.then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
.then(buff => WebAssembly.Module(buff));
```

And I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: WebAssembly.Module(): Wasm compilation exceeds internal limits in this context for the provided arguments
>       at fetch.then.then.buff (:1:77)
>       at

I don't what to make of this error and I can't find anything via web searches.

Any help is kindly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebAssembly.Module` is synchronous and some browsers don't allow large modules on the main thread to avoid having compilation block the main thread.

Try this instead:

```
fetch('hello.wasm').then(response =>
    response.arrayBuffer()
).then(buffer =>
    WebAssembly.instantiate(buffer, importObj)
).then(({module, instance}) =>
    instance.exports.f()
);
```

It's better to use [`WebAssembly.instantiate`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#webassemblyinstantiate) because it does compilation and instantiation together and allows the engine to keep at the `importObject` to make sure things look OK (especially, the `WebAssembly.Memory`).

Here I assume you want more than `main`, and instead want to invoke your module's exported function `f`.

Comment: Well yeah but in the response you gave me on an earlier question, you said that I can dynamically create the importObj which implies usage of the factory function WebAssembly.Module()

Comment: how can I create the `importObject`?

Comment: Regular uses of WebAssembly already know what the `importObject` will contain, so `WebAssembly.instance` is the right API for most. If you really don't know what it'll contain then you can use [`WebAssembly.compile`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#webassemblycompile) to get the `WebAssembly.Module`, followed by `WebAssembly.instantiate`. This is still promise-based, but breaks up compile / instantiate and allows you to create the `importObject` after getting the module.

Comment: I have managed to get a **Module** instance using **WebAssembly.compile()** but I stumbled upon another error. I will post another question for this. Thanks for your help!